# Why can't load the module?

Tags: import, module, python-3.6

Display my  `project`'s directory structure:

```
tree project
project
├── config.py
├── __init__.py
└── project.py
```

Content in project.py:

```
from . import config

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Content in `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['project','config']
from project import * 
from . import config
```

`config.py` is blank for simplicity.

To load the module:

```
cd  project
import project
```

It encounter the error info:  `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Why can't `import project`?
I found that if `project.py` renamed as `myproject.py` , keep any other thing the same as before,`import project` can work.
Does not the package `project` share same name with module `project.py` ?
Why same names matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to look at `__package__` from `project.py`, you will see that it changes from nothing when you `import project` inside the `project/` folder, and when you `import project` just outside the folder. This is because, when you are inside the folder, you are importing the **module** `project` (i.e. the `project.py` file), and from outside the `project/` folder you are importing the `project` **package** (i.e. the you are running the `__init__.py` file).

When writing `from . import x`, you expect to import `x` from inside the current package, but there is no package context, therefore it cannot `import .`

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710527/4393278

> What does `__all__` do?

> It declares the semantically "public" names from a module. If there is a name in **all**, users are expected to use it, and they can have the expectation that it will not change.

> `**all** = ['foo', 'Bar']
> means that when you import * from the module, only those names in the **all** are imported.

So you don't need to define `__all__` if you want to import anything inside `project.py` file. Also I think you should import a file is not by their path.
So, inside your `__init__` file, it should be like this.

```
from .project import *
from .config import *
```

Comment: It is a bad habbit to use `import *`!It polute namespace!